# Is it possible to get orientation theta values from edge detection using contourlet transform? (like sobel operator)

Tags: image-processing, contour, edge-detection, wavelet

I have the contourlet tool box with me in running state (Matlab)

> http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/%7Eminhdo/software/contourlet_toolbox.zip

I have seen the pyramid structure of contourlets transformation, and run some sample demo functions of it when applied to an image.
My problem is to get one matrix as a result containing detected edges information of the original information, so that I may be able to get the orientation/theta values as the edge changes in the image. Is this possible?